# Euclid's Algorithm.

Tags: euclidean-algorithm

[image]

This is a Theorem I am constructing. I have to add the last equation (the one with zero remainder) right underneath the 3 dots, but for some reason I am getting very confused. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I hope this helps. I solved it in assignment of Ring Theory in this semester only.